# How to stop Kendo React PanelBar from collapsing on typing in a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, kendo-react-ui, kendo-panelbar

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { PanelBar, PanelBarUtils } from "@progress/kendo-react-layout";

const Component=()=>{
const [value, setValue]=useSate("");
const PanalBarItems= PanelBarUtils.mapItemsToComponents([
        {
            title: "Item1",
            content:<div>
               <input value={value} onChange={(e)=>{setValue(e.value)}} />
            </div>
            uniquePrivateKey: "Item1" ,
            parentUniquePrivateKey: "PanelBar",
        },
]);
return (<PanelBar key={'PanelBar'} children={MetaDataTab} />)
}

export default Component;
```

**Whenever i try to type in input field PanelBar collapses**, i dont want it to collapse and want to continue typing. i have tried many ways listed on [kendo react](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/layout/panelbar/)

Comment: The code you have posted has a lot of errors in it. You could try and recreate your issue in a StackBlitz. Here is an example of a PanelBar with two items and they don't collapse when you type in the input: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szdp3x?file=app%2Fmain.tsx